# Component Exception (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'list.todos.filter')

Tags: react-native, components, expo, undefined

I am working on my first React app - everything has been going great but all of a sudden I started getting the error mentioned above. I am not aware of making any changes to my code and therefore for me as an absolute beginner, it is very hard to spot the error. I have been trying to fix the code for two days already and am considering starting over. All I know is that filter seems to be the problem but I cannot really see anything wrong with it. I tried looking for the answer but nothing I found really helped me solve it.

**error**

[image]

And this is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Modal } from "react-native";
import colors from "../colors";
import TodoModal from "./TodoModal";

export default class TaskList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showListVisible: false,
  };

  toggleListModal() {
    this.setState({ showListVisible: !this.state.showListVisible });
  }
  render() {
    const list = this.props.list;

    const completedCount = list.todos.filter(todo => todo.completed).length;
    const remainingCount = list.todos.length - completedCount;
```

Comment: the error is telling you that `this.props.list` is undefined. you may need to handle the case where this is undefined in `TaskList` or check in the parent component that the logic for acquiring this `list` object is correct and that it does that right then when it is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is that during the initial render, `this.props.list` is `null`. all you have to do is have a line of code to guard against that.

```
  render() {
    const list = this.props.list;

    if (!list) return null; // or return some sort of loading element

    const completedCount = list.todos.filter(todo => todo.completed).length;
    const remainingCount = list.todos.length - completedCount;
```